# Which is the better way to inheritance?

Tags: python, inheritance

Is there any difference between this:

```
class Vehicle():
    def __init__(self,  x, y):
        self.y = y
        self.x = x

class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Vehicle.__init__(self, x, y)

class Scooter(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
         Vehicle.__init__(self,  x, y)
```

and this:

```
class Vehicle():
    def __init__(self,  x, y):
         self.y = y
         self.x = x

class Car(Vehicle):
         pass            

class Scooter(Vehicle):
         pass
```

Because without `def __init__` in child classes I got the same thing, I mean `__init__` doesn't provide any effect.

Comment: The second one is not absolute inheritence as both class are not accesible from outside. Now you have changed the code

Comment: I think there is no difference, because in the first example you are basically bypassing the class `init` with itself

Comment: I would prefer the first version because you can _expand_ the `__init__`-method without overwriting the inherited code

Comment: If the `__init__` method of your subclasses doesn't do anything different than the parent class, your two versions are equivalent. In the first case, if you call `Car(x, y)`, the `__init__` method of `Car` gets called, and executes `Vehicle.__init__`. In the second case, `Car` doesn't define an `__init__`, so the parent's `__init__` gets called.

Answer (score 1):

You should't do either of them. The best way to do it is using `super`.

```
class Vehicle():
    def __init__(self,  x, y):
        self.y = y
        self.x = x

class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(Car, self).__init__(x, y)
        # super().__init__(x, y) # for python3
```

Check [this](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) blog post by Raymond Hettinger (core python contributor) on why you should be using `super`

Answer (score 0):

You need `__init__` method when you want to do child specific initialisation. Assume your child classes require another argument to be passed to the constructor and is unique to that class, in that case `__init__` method is really required.

```
class Vehicle():
    def __init__(self,  x, y):
        self.y = y
        self.x = x

class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        Vehicle.__init__(self, x, y)
        self.z = z

class Scooter(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
         Vehicle.__init__(self,  x, y)
         self.z = z
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't provide an `__init__` method in the child classes, they will just use the `__init__` method defined in their parent class (aka inheritance). In the former case, you are overriding the `__init__` method for the child classes but you are simply calling the `__init__` method of the parent class. So if you don't do that (like the later case) it will be the same. The later case automatically *inherits* the `__init__` method.

Other ways to write the same thing would be:

```
class Car(Vehicle): #This is the best way to do it though
   def __init__(self, x, y):
      super()__init__(x, y)
```

Or

```
class Car(Vehicle):
   def __init__(self, x, y):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
```

TLDR; They are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be best explained with an example.

Now take this scenario:

```
>Vehicle  ---> Car,Bike,Boat,Aeroplane,Train

>[All are vehicles right]

>Things they have in common would be (say for ex.) **Price** and **Color**
```

**However** things they won't have in common would be?

```
>**Wheels**. The total number of wheels may differ.
>

> Car-4 Bike-2 Boat-0 Aeroplane-(**Not sure**) Train-(**Many I
    guess**?)
```

But you get the point right? So When I want to just have a **Vehicle** object I don't want (or I can't tell the number of **wheels**) In that case I can initialize only with just **price and color**

However when I know the specific type of **Vehicle** say **Car** now I can `__init__` it with **number of wheels**. Now this is where object specific initializations play a major role.

A full example code of the above sample:

```
class Vehicle():
    def __init__(self,  x, y):
        self.color = y
        self.price = x
    def Horn(self):
        print("Pommm...Pommmmm!!")

class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, x, y,wheel):
        Vehicle.__init__(self, x, y)
        self.wheel = "Four Wheels man: 4"

class Scooter(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, x, y,wheel):
         Vehicle.__init__(self,  x, y)
         self.wheel = "Just Two man : 2"



VehObj = Vehicle("5000$","Black")
VehObj.Horn()
print(VehObj.color,VehObj.price)

#However note this

carObj = Car("5000$","Black",4)
print(carObj.color,carObj.price,carObj.wheel)

#Look at this

sObj = Scooter("5000$","Black",2)
print(sObj.color,sObj.price,sObj.wheel)
```

Output:

```
Pommm...Pommmmm!!
Black 5000$
Black 5000$ Four Wheels man: 4
Black 5000$ Just Two man : 2
```

Hope that cleared you up.

Answer (score -1):

Calling the init method of super class is optional if you don't wont to edit the `__init__` method of superclass.

but if you want to edit the superclass method you need custom init

```
class Vehicle():
    def __init__(self,  x, y):
        self.y = y
        self.x = x


class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        Vehicle.__init__(self, x, y)
        self.z = z
```